# Revise generic question for purposes of adding a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties

[Extracting files from CloneZilla images](https://serverfault.com/questions/35639/extracting-files-from-clonezilla-images)

I want to add a bounty to that question, but the question is ambiguous because they don't mention whether or not they want answers for Linux or Windows.

It already has a good Linux answer. I want to find a Windows answer.

Would it be bad form to modify the question to specifically ask for a Windows answer for the purposes of the bounty? Or should I be asking a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much activity on the question, so I'd just go ahead and set the bounty and add a comment on the question saying what you're looking for specifically.

Regardless of the bounty, edits to a question should *never* change the meaning, particularly if it would invalidate an existing answer.

Comment: Yeah, this was what I was thinking. I've gone and done what you suggested, as it seemed to back up my own thinking. This way the context of the question stays the same.